# Why do I have tens of "Open PHP Type" folders in my Eclipse toolbar?

Tags: eclipse

I use Eclipse with PyDev as my usual IDE. Recently I noticed that there is a whole row of greyed-out `Open PHP Type` folders on my toolbar at the top of the screen as shown in this image.

[image: Screenshot]

Why are they there and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: Having earned me a tumbleweed badge on here, I think this might be better off at SO!

Answer (score 3):

How to get rid of them:

1. Go to menu Window > Customize Perspective
2. Open the tab Toolbar Visibility
3. Expand the Search group
4. Disable all occurences of "Open PHP Type"

From the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9n.htm)

Comment: They're all already unchecked. For now I've got rid of the search group entirely as I always access it with shortcut keys anyway.

Comment: I had about ten icons like this too. But why? One day I opened eclipse and I had these disabled icons too. With eclipse everything feels like some kind of magic (dark, very dark magic though).